# CodeIgniter showing different menu using If statement

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, if-statement

I have an error in the variable when I try to get the value it says it was undefined While I have already stored the session of the variable "$level" and sent it to the view but the condition of the variable become undefined, is there anything wrong with the code?

The variable that I get is from the login. Also I have tried to call the $level and it work

I have tried to use foreach and non foreach method still none of these are working

View.php

```
<?php if($level->level == '1') ?>
<p>Number 1</p>
<?php if($level->level == '2') ?>
<p>Number 2</p>
```

admin.php

```
function index(){       
$level = $this->session->userdata('level');
$this->load->view('view',$level);
}
```

Login.php

```
public function do_login()
    {
        $u = $this->input->post("user");
        $p = md5($this->input->post("pass"));

        $cari = $this->model_pesawat->cek_login($u, $p)->row();
        $hitung = $this->model_pesawat->cek_login($u, $p)->num_rows();

        if ($hitung > 0) {

        $data = array('admin_id' => $cari->no_user ,
                            'admin_user' => $cari->username, 
                            'admin_nama' => $cari->nama,
                            'level' => $cari->level,
                            'admin_valid' => TRUE
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('admin','refresh');
        }else{
            echo "maaf username atau password salah";
        }   
    }
```

I want the result the if statement will show different value in the view depending on the $level of the user

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass array to the CodeIginter view.

And the array's keys will be used as individual elements in view.

Its similar to [extract()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function.

So, you should pass `$data` and add `$level` into it.

```
$data['level'] = $level;
$this->load->view('view', $data);
```

In your view, you can access `$level` from Controller as `$level`.

No need to care for `$data`

Comment: I tried using ```if($level->level == '1')``` but it still didn't work it says undefined level, but I already make sure I can call the value of the level when i'm using echo

Answer (score 0):

**In view you can directly use session variable, no need to pass from controller**

```
<p>Number 1</p>
<?php if($this->session->userdata('level') == '2') ?>
<p>Number 2</p>
```

Comment: Sorry I just edited my code again, but when I used your code it show all of the value instead, like you don't use the if statement

Answer (score 0):

you should check data in session, whether it's getting stored or not.

```
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($this->session->userdata());
```

Comment: I have tried it when I'm calling the level at the controller using

echo $level; there is the value but when I put it on the view it says undefined/non property object

Comment: In Controler, echo following and check whether it's declared?






        echo $this->session->userdata('level'); exit;

Comment: Yes I saw number 3 in the page which is the record value